# Django ORM inside of AWS Lambda function

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, aws-lambda

I am looking to move away from celery and start using AWS Lambda to generate my files and store into S3. After I save on S3, I would like to be able to save a reference to my Django Database (being hosted on RDS). Am I able to do this on Lambda?

Or would an option be that I generate the file, save to s3 and send the reference to my currently hosted Django application? My app is currently being hosted on an EC2 instance. I know Zappa exists but am wondering if redeploying my entire application would be overkill.

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this? We're looking at doing this to alleviate peak load from our batch server.

Comment: @PabloDiaz I haven't sadly.